# Python code behaving differently depending on where it's been launched from

Tags: python, eclipse, notepad++, python-idle

I'm using Notepad++ to write an application in Python and I've found that it executes differently depending on how I launch it. This application uses threads to read the serial bus while also allowing commands to be written. It also provides an option to save a log of the console to a file.

- In Notepad++ (using NppExec) everything runs fine, since this is where I'm testing.
- In the Windows command line, I get '`AttributeError: 'Logger' object had no attribute 'errors'`'
- In IDLE, the program runs but with slightly different formatting (extra newline chars appearing after each byte is read from serial)
- In Eclipse (using PyDev) it again runs fine albeit seemingly doubling up newlines

They seems to be interpreting the code differently. This is a work in progress so I'm sure there are errors in the code, but what kinds of errors could produce such different symptoms?? Which should I trust??

Comment: Maybe it's a race condition that's expressing itself in different ways depending on how much load the rest of the system is under. I'd expect Notepad to consume more resources than the command line, for example. The solution would be to identify the race condition in your code and guard against it with locks or similar.

Comment: You could be running the code with different Python interpreters, or with different environment variables (a different PYTHONPATH could make a big difference for example). Too many variables to be sure without seeing code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: I have edited with N++ but have run python only from Idle and the console.  Except for non-ascii output, I regard the latter as the standard.  Since Idle does not use the logging module, I am surprised that Idle would not get the same error as the console.